# ngx-translate with angular material 2 MdSnackBar

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material2

I'm new to TS and Angular 4. I need to be able to show a user a translated `CLOSE` word inside the angular material 2 `MdSnackBar`. I've understood that you can call the ngx-translate translation service from within the code like this:

```
this.translate.get('ERROR.CLOSE').subscribe((res: string) => {
     console.log(res);
});
```

The thing is that I need to be able to show this inside an angular material 2 element called `MdSnackBar`.

I wanted to execute it like this:

```
this.snackBar.open(error, this.getCloseWord(), {
     duration: 10000,
})

private getCloseWord() {
    this.translate.get('ERROR.CLOSE').subscribe((res: string) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

But I don't know how to make the `getCloseWord()` method to return a correct string value out of an observable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as follow:

```
public someMethod() {
  const error = ...some error...;
  ...
  this.translate.get('ERROR.CLOSE').subscribe(( res: string ) => {
    this.snackBar.open(error, res, { duration: 10000 });
  });
  ...
}
```

The ".get()" function returns an Observable so just open your snackbar when "get" is subscribed. Then you know that your translation is available.

---

A solution with more than one observer could be as follows:

```
public someMethod() {
    const newObserver = new ReplaySubject();
    let error = null;
    let close = null;

    this.translate.get('ERROR.MESSAGE').subscribe( (translation: string) => {
        error = translation;
        newObserver.next();
    });

    this.translate.get('ERROR.CLOSE').subscribe( (translation: string) => {
        close = translation;
        newObserver.next();
    });

    newObserver.subscribe( () => {
        if(error && close) {
            this.snackBar.open(error, close, { duration: 10000 });
        }
    });
}
```

Or the best solution is to merge them:

```
import "rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin";
...
public someMethod(){
   const firstTranslationObs = this.translate.get('ERROR.MESSAGE');
   const secondTranslationObs = this.translate.get('ERROR.CLOSE');

   Observable.forkJoin([firstTranslationObs, secondTranslationObs])
      .subscribe(results => {
        let error= results[0];
        let close = results[1];
        this.snackBar.open(error, close, { duration: 10000 });
      });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works like a charm! What if I want translations for two elements at the same time. How can I adjust the request to request for two parameters?