# How to have angular translate of for multiple values in a ts file and also having the parameters?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-translate

```
this.snackBar.open(
            `Only files of size less than ${this.fileSizeAllowed}KB are allowed`,
            this.translate.instant('USER_REG.close'),
            
            {
              panelClass: 'errorSnackbar',
              duration: 5500,
            }
          );
```

I just want the message present in the snackBar, i.e, "Only files of size less than" to be translated to another language, followed by the dynamic variable and then the line "KB are allowed"is to be translated.How to do it? Completely new to angular translate!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this answer can help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45737562/13331446

Have you tried to do the following?

```
this.snackBar.open(
            this.translate.instant('FIRST.MESSAGE')+ ${this.fileSizeAllowed} + this.translate.instant('SECOND.MESSAGE'),
            this.translate.instant('USER_REG.close'),
            
            {
              panelClass: 'errorSnackbar',
              duration: 5500,
            }
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `translate.instant` method from within the template string literal. Mind the space after the word `than`. If the translate service removes the space you can add it right after the first `${}` block.

```
this.snackBar.open(
`${this.translate.instant('Only files of size less than ')}${this.fileSizeAllowed}${this.translate.instant('KB are allowed')}`, 
this.translate.instant('USER_REG.close'), 
{ panelClass: 'errorSnackbar', duration: 5500, } 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use parameters like in the code below

```
    this.snackBar.open(
this.translateService.stream('MESSAGEKEY', { dynamicVariable: this.fileSizeAllowed}).subscribe((res) => { return res; })
this.translate.instant('USER_REG.close'),                
                {
                  panelClass: 'errorSnackbar',
                  duration: 5500,
                };
    );
```

and in your resource file the value will be

```
'MESSAGEKEY' : "Only files of size less than" {{ dynamicVariable }} "KB are allowed"
```